# Regex to match phone number 5ABCDYYZZ

Tags: python, regex

I am using regex to classify special numbers.

The pattern I wish to match looks like this : `5ABCDXXYY`.

Its a number that:

- starts with "5"
- followed by 4 different digits (`ABCD`)
- then 2 matching digits (`XX`)
- and again 2 matching digits (`YY`)

examples the regex should match:
`590631122`, `510367722`
examples the regex shouldn't match:
`566781100`, `519283412`

I have tried the below

```
S_E_4_A = 590631122
S_E_4_A_pattern = re.sub(r'.{4}\d(\d)\1(\d)\2', "Special-Private", str(S_E_4_A))
print(S_E_4_A_pattern)
```

The problem with my regex is that it also match other patterns such as `5ABXXYYZZ`.

I want to change my regex to match only two sets of repeating numbers and not more.

Thank you

Comment: Is in your sample the digit on the 2nd index (9) not the same as the one on the 5th index? And therefor your pattern is `5ABCAXXYY`?

Comment: Do you mean that in the ABCD-part no direct neighbor digits should be equal?

Comment: Also, what if 'A' equals 5? Is that allowed? Rather include more sample data.

Comment: I want the regex to match `5ABCDXXYY`. Not `5ABZZXXYY` or `5BBZZXXYY`. The only constraint is to match two sets `XXYY` and not more.

Comment: Yes. I tested it. it does not work

Comment: Are the matches [in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/UzgSCF/1) those you want?

Comment: @bobblebubble: *I think* here `5` has to be first digit

Comment: @anubhava thx! [updated version of idea](https://regex101.com/r/uym45e/1) :) It's only guessing, I wonder if the string may start with eg `55`. Maybe you can make the requirements more clear @Leena! !!

Comment: And my answer below shows exact same matches as your demo @bobblebubble but may be there are some requirements not clearly drafted.

Comment: I just nocticed @anubhava - At first glance I've somehow overlooked your nice lookahead check, was a bit confused by use of `\w` imho the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex checks the pattern you're requesting for:

```
(?!.*(\d)\1(\d)\2(\d)\3).{4}\d(\d)\4(\d)\5
```

[Link](https://regex101.com/r/eJu01Z/1) to Demo.

Explanation:
The negative lookahead at the beginning checks if there isn't a pattern ZZXXYY (more than two sets of couples) in the subsequent string match.

Comment: Thank you. However, I want the regex to match 5ABCDXXYY. Not 5ABZZXXYY or 5BBZZXXYY. The only constraint is to match two sets XXYY and not more.

Comment: My goal is to match any number with that pattern not just the given sample

Comment: Ok, can you check again, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex to validate your constraints:

```bash
\b(?!.{0,3}(\w)\1)5\w{4}(\d)\2(\d)\3\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sHr0SX/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?!.(\w)\1)`: Negative lookahead to ensure we don't have a repeat of any chat after 0 to 3 chars
- `5`: Match digit `5`
- `\w{4}`: Match 4 word characters
- `(\d)`: Match a digit in capture group #2
- `\2`: Match same value as in capture group #2
- `(\d)`: Match a digit in capture group #3
- `\3`: Match same value as in capture group #3
- `\b`: Word boundary

Comment: @Leena: Can you let me know for which input text it didn't work

Comment: Looks good this, also to use the lookahead once!

Answer (score 1):

You can capture each digit and use a backreference within a negative lookahead pattern to ensure that it does not repeat where you don't it to:

```
\b5(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(?!\2)(\d)(?!\3)(\d)(?!\4)(\d)\5(?!\5)(\d)\6\b
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/24fdFi/1

Comment: It does not work with the given pattern